# Create html table as string based on textbox value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have textbox and a button on my aspx page.

Now I want to create a html table as string on button click event. I have done this task. Please look at my below code:

```
        string stsrtest = "test";
        string nWidth="150px";          
        string strHtml = "<table><tr><td width= '" + nWidth + "'> Authorized By</td><td>Employee </td><td>Status</td><td>Date </td><td>Note</td><td>Signutare</td></tr>";
        strHtml += "<tr><td> " + stsrtest + "</td><td> " + stsrtest + "</td><td> " + stsrtest + "</td><td> " + stsrtest + "</td><td> " + stsrtest + "</td><td>test</td></tr>";
        strHtml += "</table>";
```

Now I want to create row and column dyanically based on textbox value.

For Example if textbox value is 15 then I want create a table with 3 column and 5 Rows.
and if textbox value is 6  then I want create a table with 3 column and 2 Rows.

I have use above code to create a simple 2 rows and 5 column.

Comment: You need to use factorization algorithm for that.....

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue using below code:

```
        int nTotal = Convert.ToInt32(txtCell.Text);
        int nRows = 0;
        int nLast = nTotal % 3;
        nRows = nTotal / 3;
        string strHmtl = "<table border='1px' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'  style='height: 28px; width: 647px;' >";

        for (int i = 0; i < nTotal - nTotal % 3; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i % 3 == 0)
                strHmtl += "<tr>";
            strHmtl += "<td></td>";
            if (i % 3 == 2)
                strHmtl += "</tr>";
        }
        if (nTotal % 3 != 0)
        {
            strHmtl += "<tr>";
            if (nLast == 1)
                strHmtl += "<td> </td>";               
            else
            {
                strHmtl += "<td>  </td>";
                strHmtl += "<td>  </td>";
            }
            strHmtl += "</tr>";
        }
        strHmtl += "</table>";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just build your table dynamically by setting the number of your columns and looping for each row to build it as string. Take a look at this example:

```
    StringBuilder l_strBuilder= new StringBuilder();
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<table">");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<th>Authorized By</th>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<th>Employee</th>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<th>Status</th>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<th>Date</th>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<th>Note</th>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<th>Signutare</th>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWSNUMBER; i++)
    {
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<td>column 1 data</td>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<td>column 2 data</td>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<td>column 3 data</td>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<td>column 4 data</td>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<td>column 5 data</td>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("<td>column 6 data</td>");
            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");
    }

            l_strBuilder.AppendLine("</table>");
```

After the building the table you can use the asp literal obj to put your table in your page.

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrDynTable" runat="server" />
```

And fill it with your string this way:

```
ltrDynTable.Text = l_strBuilder.ToString();
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply but I want to create Row and column based on textbox value which I have mention in my question with example and i also want to give cell value like for cell one its 1,for cell value its 2,...etc.